# Discovery Script is not working

Tags: powershell, discovery, scom

Below is my script with identifiers scrubbed. The Base Class for Diagnostics is MyCompany.MyApp and the base class of that is Windows Computer. If I run this on the target machine directly with parameters I am getting XML returned. If I run from my PC it is blank. That makes sense locally, but I thought when you run discoveries that the agent runs it on the machine you are targeting? All my other discoveries thus far have been registry so it is possible I am doing something completely wrong.

```
Param($sourceId, $managedEntityId, $ComputerName)

$api = New-Object -ComObject 'MOM.ScriptAPI'
$discoveryData = $api.CreateDiscoveryData(0, $SourceId, $ManagedEntityId)

$Diagnostics = Invoke-Command -ComputerName $ComputerName {
    Get-WebApplication -Name "diagnostics"
}

foreach ($x in $Diagnostics)
{
    $instance = $discoveryData.CreateClassInstance("$MPElement[Name='MyCompany.MyApp.Diagnostics']$")
    $instance.AddProperty("$MPElement[Name='Windows!Microsoft.Windows.Computer']/PrincipalName$", $ComputerName)
    $discoveryData.AddInstance($instance)
}
```

Answer (score 0):

As the first, most obvious reason, you don't output the discovery data onto output stream (StdOut). Just simple add `$discoveryData` at a new line by the end of your script.

Moreover, more information about your class and MP architecture required. I'd probably recommend you to use `Windows!Microsoft.Windows.ComputerRole` as base class and host it on target computer object.

Regards
Max